# Page displays apex scripts while using render="true" in <apex:page message> visualforce page?reasons?

Tags: rendered, pagemessages

When I am  trying to display page message in vf page I am getting the following issue and that is because of using rendered="true"

Page getting displayed with following code:
[image: Displays Scripts]

visualforce page code:

```
        <apex:pageMessage summary="{!myMsg1}" severity="error" strength="2" rendered="true" />
```

How can I stop getting it?Any solutions?

Comment: have you included that script in your vf page anywhere?

Comment: could you put your code of entire page?

Comment: have edited it@ Nitin and kurunve

Comment: @Pril thats not entire page. I am pretty sure that piece, which you put as code here and screenshot have no common part

Comment: @Pril are you using renderas="pdf" ?

Comment: Yeah @kurunve I have pasted the code only for the button for which I am displaying the message.And screen shot is for that piece only

Comment: no@tushar.I have not used it

Comment: @Pril problem is that you messed up VF page, especially part with scripts. By some reason, there is **<script>** tag before **<apex:pageMessage ... >**. Remove that and it will work better

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not closed your Script tags .

Please close your Script tags else they are considered as plain texts

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jhefj/kdhefjsgh/jquery"/>
```